# Magnetic surface removal

Tags: solutions

I have a DIY project made from used hard disk. Certain HDD models contain precision glass disks plated with magnetic surface, usually done with magnetron sputtering. I am searching for a substance I can use to etch that magnetic surface to reach glass. Would be nice to have solution for etching with photoresist solution or complete removal. Wikipedia says magnetic surface consists of several layers, mostly metallic and non-magnetic, but I have no clue what metals are used and I guess its patented. Is there any guess of chemical process which I can try?

Comment: Modern hard drives use layered materials to take advantage of magnetostrictive effects. If there is an Fe layer, the standard etchant Nital may do the trick, but the layering could cause issues.